# How does Facebook's local Javascript SDK resolve dependencies?

Tags: facebook, api, dependencies, javascript

I downloaded the source code of Facebook's Javascript SDK from github. At the top of each javascript file, there is a header, such as the following:

/*
 * @provides fb.content
 * @requires fb.prelude fb.array
 */

Are these simply for the sake of the programmer so that (s)he knows which files are required by each file?   Or is there a program that processes these comments and adds the proper files so that all required files are available?

Thanks for the help.

Repo link for Facebook's Javascript SDK: https://github.com/facebook/connect-js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like it's just [JSDoc documentation](http://code.google.com/p/jsdoc-toolkit/wiki/FAQ) to me.  So to answer your question, it is for the sake of the programmer, and for anyone who reads the API reference that is generated from the script files.